# Python while (bool):

Tags: python, logic

In this case:

```
swag = True
i = 0

while swag:
    i=i+1
    print(swag)
    if i == 3:
        swag = False
```

Will the while loop exit after 3 turns?

Does while swag - check if swag exists or if swag is True

Comment: For your first question - `Why don't you run it and check`? For your 2nd question - It checks whether swag is True or not.

Comment: Dude, you've even got a print statement. Run it and count the number of times you see "True"

Comment: I ran it before I asked the question - but it resulted in an infinite while loop for some reason, so hence, I wanted to check on Stack Overflow. Please don't downvote this. Checking can't hurt can it?

Comment: @RohitRayudu:  You *think* this was the code you ran.  This code will not result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe I didn't type it correctly with indentation in the terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`while swag:` will run while `swag` is "truthy", which it will be while `swag` is `True`, and will not be when you set `swag` to `False`.

Comment: +1 for “truthy” because it will actually evaluate the expression (whatever it is) to a boolean value.

Answer (score 4):

> Does while swag - check if swag exists or if swag is True

It checks if `swag` is `True` (or [*"truthy"*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), I should say). And yes, the loop will exit after 3 iterations because `i=i+1` must be executed *3 times* until `i == 3` and (by the `if`-statement) `swag` is set to `False`, at which point the loop will exit.

But why not check this yourself?

```
swag = True
i = 0

while swag:
    i=i+1
    print(swag)
    if i == 3:
        swag = False
```

```
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also shorten your expression to increment variable 'i' by 1 by using the following notation:
i+=1 (same as i=i+1)